# What is the equivalent of <composite-element> in Castle ActiveRecord?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

I have a `TrackLog` that has a collection of `TrackPoints`:

```
public class TrackLog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ISet<TrackPoint> TrackPoints { get; set; }
}

public class TrackPoint
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to map the track points as a collection of components, as this makes the most sense. According to the book ***NHibernate in Action***, on page 187:

> Collections of components are mapped similarily to other collections of value type instances. The only difference is the use of `<composite-element>` in place of the familiar `<element>` tag.

How would I do this using Castle ActiveRecord attributes?

## Solution:

To expand on Mauricio's answer, the correct mapping is like so:

```
[ActiveRecord]
public class TrackLog
{
    [Property]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [HasMany(DependentObjects = true,
             MapType = typeof(TrackPoint),
             Table = "TrackPoint",
             ColumnKey = "TrackLog_Id"
    )]
    public ISet<TrackPoint> TrackPoints { get; set; }
}
```

You must provide the `MapType`, `Table`, and `ColumnKey` properties in addition to `DependentObjects`.

`MapType`: the type of the class you want to map to

`Table`: name of the table in the database for the component list

`ColumnKey`: name of the foreign key column used to relate the child to the parent

## Update:

You cannot use `Set` as the `RelationType`. It will cause NHibernate to exhibit some weird behavior, where it saves the entities, deletes them, and the re-saves two copies of each element. In the case of my `TrackLog`, it saved 25 `TrackPoints`, deleted them, then saved the 25 `TrackPoints` again two times, for a total of 50. Then when the `SessionScope` was disposed, it saved another 25, for a total of 75 `TrackPoints` instead of the expected 25. I couldn't find out the source of this problem, but the fix is to avoid using `Set` and use `Bag` (or something else, I only tested it with `Bag`) instead.

Comment: @Daniel: can you please add that to the wiki? http://stw.castleproject.org I've never really used DependentObjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DependentObjects = true`, e.g.:

```
public class TrackLog {
   [Property]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [HasMany(DependentObjects = true)]
   public ISet<TrackPoint> TrackPoints { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you in charge of the Castle ActiveRecord official documentation at all? I believe this would be good to add to the section on mapping components.

Comment: +1. BTW Anyone can contribute to Castle's documentation. You too Daniel :)